# SendMessage PostMessage to simulate click on other application won't fire the Click event

Tags: c#, events, vb6, sendmessage

I'm trying to build a program that simulates the click in a PictureBox of another app.

The target app is built in VB6.

I have develop a test app to see what happen in the events of the PictureBox when I try to send the events.

I'm using this code in C#:

```
SendMessage(0x007E147C, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, fMakeLong(150,150));

Thread.Sleep(100);

SendMessage(0x007E147C, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, fMakeLong(150,150));
```

`0x007E147C` is the handle of the PictureBox, I got it with Spy++.

if I click the PictureBox in the app I got this in the log:

> MouseDown: 1 0 337 155

> MouseUp: 1 0 337 155

> Click

1 fire for MouseDown, 1 for MouseUp and 1 for Click.

But if I send the messages I only get the MouseDown and MouseUp events but not the Click event.

If I use the message: `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` I can simulate the `DblClick` event, but there is no message for the simple click, at least that I know of.

Is there any other message I need to send to simulate that event?

Thanks.

Comment: Something I realise is that if I hold the mouse left click down while sending the event, then it detect the click event, it doesn't matter if its outside the window as long as the mouse button is down, it will fire the click event when the MOUSEUP event is sent.

Comment: Perhaps try [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead of SendMessage?

Comment: If I do a sendinput for clickdown I can simulate my mouse down and it kind of work, but the idea is to send the message in background without having the app maximized, so this works but halfway, ideally I would like to simulate the click event even with the window minimized, for dbl click I can do it but not for click.